# R manipulating multiple data frames using a lapply

Tags: r

I need to check whether several data frames are empty and assign a value if they are empty. I use the following code for this

```
a =  data.frame()
b =  data.frame()

x =  list(a, b)

cc =  lapply(x, function(x)
        if(is.data.frame(x) && nrow(x)==0){
          x= data.frame("11111")
        })
```

However this results in a list. I would like to know whether there is a method to do this manipulation without putting the data frames in a list

Comment: You need to also have `else` to return 'x'  If there are multiple data.frames, it is better to keep it in a `list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like akrun said, you should have an else-branch that returns the x in case it is not empty, right now your code always produces empty. Otherwise, I'd also prepare a suitable empty data.frame, if you will always have a certain columns in your data. This is code using by preparing columns with notation e.g. numeric(0), character(0), integer(0) and so forth.

```
emptyframe = data.frame(num = numeric(0), name = character(0))

a = emptyframe
b = data.frame(num = 1:2, name = paste("ID", 1:2))
c = data.frame(num = 6:8, name = paste("ID", 6:8))
d = emptyframe

x =  list(a, b, c, d)

combined =  lapply(x, function(x){
    if(is.data.frame(x) && nrow(x)==0){
        # Creating an empty data frame you'd preferably want to know before-hand what kind of variables you will have
        emptyframe
    }else{ # I would also cast it data.frame before returning, as it may have just failed cause of is.data.frame == FALSE
        as.data.frame(x)
    }
})

combined

#> combined
#[[1]]
#[1] num  name
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#
#[[2]]
#  num name
#1   1 ID 1
#2   2 ID 2
#
#[[3]]
#  num name
#1   6 ID 6
#2   7 ID 7
#3   8 ID 8
#
#[[4]]
#[1] num  name
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

If your empty data.frames are consistent, there's a lot of neat stuff you can then do with the data.frames using the above approach, as they are considered to be regular.  For example, consider row-binding them into a single bigger data.frame:

```
do.call("rbind", combined)

#> do.call("rbind", combined)
#  num name
#1   1 ID 1
#2   2 ID 2
#3   6 ID 6
#4   7 ID 7
#5   8 ID 8
```